# woocommerce: i want to show the name and price in the buy button with php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello on the archive page i want to show the price and product name in the "add to chart" button. 
I want to do this with this code. but i only get or the price or the name.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 
'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text');

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {
global $product;
$link = $product->get_name();
    return __( $link  , 'woocommerce' );
  }
```

i know the "get_price()"will get me the price.

Comment: have you tried this merge? $link = $product->get_name().' '.$product->get_price();

Comment: thx that did it. it works.